# How to display many to many jpa collection in jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

i made many to many join table between users and groups tables .
so i have a collection in each entitie ( Users and groups )

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "usersCollection")
    private Collection<Groups> groupsCollection;
```

and i want to display groups collection in Jsf thats what i did :

```
<p:dataTable var="user" value="#{usergestion.tableusers}">  
                           <p:column headerText="username">  
                               <h:outputText value="#{user.username}" />  
                           </p:column>  

                           <p:column headerText="nom">  
                               <h:outputText value="#{user.nom}" />  
                           </p:column>  

                           <p:column headerText="prenom">  
                               <h:outputText value="#{user.prenom}" />  
                           </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="groupe"> 

                                <h:outputText value="#{user.groupsCollection.get(0)}"  />

                           </p:column>
```

and that what i get :
[image]

how i can get just the nombre not com.database.Groups[ idGroups=2 ]  ???

**Solution :**

i used : `<h:outputText value="#{user.groupsCollection.get(0).groupname}"  />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You normally use an iterating component such as `<ui:repeat>` or `<h:dataTable>` to iterate over a collection. You can perfectly nest it inside another iterating component.

E.g.

```html
<p:column headerText="groupe"> 
    <ui:repeat value="#{user.groupsCollection}" var="groups">
        <h:outputText value="#{groups.groupname}" /><br/>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:column>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you've there some poor naming convention. One group should be represented by a class named `Group`, not `Groups`. I suggest to rename the one and other so that the code becomes so much more self documenting:

```html
<p:column headerText="groups"> 
    <ui:repeat value="#{user.groups}" var="group">
        <h:outputText value="#{group.name}" /><br/>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:column>
```

The plural `s` in the field/variable name should already be indicative that it concerns a collection.

Comment: Hi BalusC! I have one row in my table in db and doing this results in datable showing this row two times.. Only difference I use h:column, pure jsf.

Comment: @10101101: This problem is not caused by JSF. You would observe exactly the same problem when using a different presenter of the model, such as `System.out.println()` directly after retrieving the results. The real problem is in your database query. Most probably you're missing out a `DISTINCT` or a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You are a boss :D Thanks!