# jsf - foreign key in datatable

Tags: jpa, datatable

I'm showing a list of Orders in a datatable , and one of its columns must show the customer_id of that order: customer_id is a fk in ManyToOne relationship.

**Customer entity**

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    ///other columns

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Order> orders;
```

**Order entity**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "orders")

public class Order implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;


    @Column (nullable = false)
    private String state;

    @Column (nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar openingDate;

    @Column (nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar closingDate;

    @Column (nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar evadingDate;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE },fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id") 
    private Customer customer;
```

and finally, this is the page where i'm putting the datatable with all the orders.

**showOrders.xhtml**

```
<h:dataTable id="list" value="#{orderController.orders}"
        var="order">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Nome</f:facet>
            <h:commandLink action="#{orderController.findOrder}"
                value="#{order.id}" style="color: orange">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{orderController.id}"
                    value="#{order.id}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Stato</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{order.state}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Data Apertura</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{order.openingDate.time}">
                <f:convertDateTime datestyle="full" type="date" />
            </h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Data Chiusura</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{order.closingDate.time}">
                <f:convertDateTime datestyle="full" type="date" />
            </h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Data Evasione</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{order.evadingDate.time}">
                <f:convertDateTime datestyle="full" type="date" />
            </h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">ID Cliente</f:facet>
            <h:commandLink action="#{registerCustomer.detailsCustomer}"
                value="#{order.customer.id}" style="color: orange">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{registerCustomer.id}"
                    value="#{order.customer.id}" /> 
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:column>
```

Problem is, everything is fine except the customer_id, which doesn't show on the page. What am I do wrong?
I've tried looot of things, changed type of fetching, changed the relationships...but i'm start to thinking it's a java problem , even if i can't really find the solution or some explanation about it on the internet. Could someone help me? I'm stuck :/

Comment: Where do you display `customer_id`? Is it here `value="#{order.customer.id}"`? The field is lazily fetched (`FetchType.LAZY`). You may need to prefetch but it is completely invisible as to how you get a list of orders associated with a particular customer. Additionally,  setting `CascadeType.REMOVE` on `@ManyToOne` relationships does not make sense. It will remove the associated parent (a `Customer` row) whenever one of its children is removed. As a consequence, its remaining children are likely to become orphan depending upon the cascade type set on the foreign key column in the table.

Comment: @Tiny that's true, I want to display it right there, but it doesn't.
Are you saying that I should change the fetching to eager?

btw i'll clear that 'CascadeType.REMOVE' right now, don't know why it's been there (unfortunately i'm working with another person, so not the entire code is mine)

Comment: Nope. Using `FetchType.EAGER` unnecessarily is the worst case ever. Guessing the exact symptom based on the given question's description is difficult. Are you sure about the value of `#{order.customer.id}`? It is likely that its value is correctly fetched but it does not set properly to a managed bean property associated with `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` i.e. `target="#{registerCustomer.id}"` for some unclear reasons?

Comment: @Tiny i don't know if that's the case, but anyway that `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` is used to pass the parameter and executing the detailsCustomer method of the bean.
The main problem is that I can't even see the customer id value on the datatable

Comment: @Enduavon do you have the set and get method for the customer_id : getCustomer and setCustomer ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia yes of course!

Comment: maybe this can help you ? http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/four-solutions-to-lazyinitializationexc_05.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy to say I found the solution! (kudos for @Mauricio Gracia to enlight my finding-a-solution path)

First, I removed the "fetch = FetchType.LAZY" from the customer relationship in Order class

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id") 
private Customer customer;
```

Then, I serialized the Customer class

```
   @Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

And everything works fine, I can see the customer id in my .xhtml page :))
However, I don't know if this is a good practice but I think I can take the risk in a small university project like this! Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Order` is related to a `Customer` here is what you need to do to still use LAZY loading but be able to initilize the customer of a given order

```
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        ord = (Order) session.get(Order.class, id_order);
        Hibernate.initialize(ord.getCustomer());
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        Customer cust = ord.getCustomer();
```

Also check that you have the set and get related to the customer_id JOIN

```
Customer getCustomer() { }
setCustomer(Customer cust) { }
```

Comment: hello Mauricio, thanks for the answer. I'm not using Hibernate and i'm using EJB for connecting to the database. How can I write this method with @EJB and what it does exactly?

Comment: Enduavon: You're confusing "EJB" with "JPA". Mauricio: You're confusing "(Legacy) Hibernate Core" with "Hibernate EntityManager".

Comment: yea sorry @BalusC, i know the difference though :)
Btw, you should know what am I doing wrong. Any idea?

Comment: @Enduavon so if you try to display order.getCustomer().customer_id it works ?

Comment: @BalusC thanks for pointing that out in fact the question needs better tagging to avoid this ;-)

Comment: All I know is that it's not a Java/JSF problem. You'd likely have exactly the same problem when printing/logging `order.getCustomer().getId()` directly after retrieving it from EJB, before JSF presents it (i.e. JSF is merely the "presenter" here, it does not manipulate the retrieved model in any way). I suggest to reduce the JSF nuisance in the question and retarget from [jsf] to [jpa] to make it better focused.

Comment: @Enduavon so you are finally using HibernateCore ?  Hibernate EntityManager ? or what ? (I am very new to this but willing to help you and learn in the process)

Comment: @MauricioGracia appreciate your help! But i'm using JPA, not hibernate :D

Comment: @BalusC Please can You help me? I have many to many relation between two tables: Repair and Failure (related to mobile repair shop). Every Repair can have many device Failures, and also every device Failure can be in many Repairs. So I made a helper Entity called RepairFailure. It works well. Now I have datatable which presents all repairs. Every row in table represents single Repair. One of its columns is Failures... Here I am stuck. How can I show in this column all Failures related to Repair? It can be anything, even for example all Failures in single String, separated by commas?

Comment: You should see if you problem is solved already here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=many+to+many+jsf and if not you need to create a new question.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Tanks budddy, did same as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417247/how-to-display-many-to-many-jpa-collection-in-jsf and now get: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role.. And btw I want to dodge and dunk over FetchType.EAGER ;)